# Выбрать два checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который выбирает один чекбокс. Как можно сделать, чтобы была возможность выбора двух из трех вариантов

```js
$('.cchl').click(function(){
  var kol = $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
  if(kol == 2){
      $(".cchl").removeAttr("checked");
  $(this).prop("checked", true); 
  }
});
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="import" value="Чекбокс 1" class="cchl">
 <input type="checkbox" name="import" value="Чекбокс 2" class="cchl">
 <input type="checkbox" name="import" value="Чекбокс 3" class="cchl">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.cchl').click(function(){
  var kol = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  if(kol > 2){
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="import[]" value="Чекбокс 1" class="cchl">
<input type="checkbox" name="import[]" value="Чекбокс 2" class="cchl">
<input type="checkbox" name="import[]" value="Чекбокс 3" class="cchl">
```